# How to build a deterministic or non deterministic finite automat for a language

Tags: finite-automata

$L_1$ and $L_2$ are two languages that have a finite deterministic automaton. $Σ = \{0,1\}$ for the two languages.

Let $L=\{x∈L_1\mid \text{there exists } y∈L_2,\text{such that } \#_0(x)=\#_0(y)\}$, here $\#_0(x)$ means the number of times $0$ appears in $x$.

This means we keep every word in $L_1$ if there is a word in $L_2$ where the number of $0$ in both words is equal.
I need to prove that $L$ has a deterministic finite automaton. I need to build this automaton .
I don't even know where to start. Would anyone be able to help me with this problem?

Answer (score 6):

A possible approach is to change the language $L_2$. We only need to check the number of $0$'s in its strings, not the number of $1$'s nor the positions of the $1$'s.

Thus replace all $1$'s in the automaton for $L_2$ by $\lambda$-transitions, and make the resulting automaton over $\{0\}$ deterministic again. Then, add loops with $1$ at every state of the automaton, to allow arbitrary letters $1$, at arbitrary places.

Finally we can apply the product construction for intersection on original automaton for $L_1$ and the new automaton for $L'_2$.

Comment: Can I solve this question the same way if I do not turn the resulting automaton to deterministic again? Or do I need to add some changes? I just do not know how to turn it back to deterministic  in a general way without knowing the automaton. I do not have a problem if the result is a non-deterministic automaton.

Comment: @ella Computing the intersection of regular languages can also be done with nondeterministic finite automata and the usual direct product construction. No problem.

Comment: (ctd.) On second tought: the $\lambda$-transitions that result from removing the $1$-symbols, do form a challenge when using the product construction.